# Обращение к файлу напрямую в Linux

Tags: linux

Допустим я нахожусь в директории `/dir` с правами `root`

В этой директории есть пустой файл `file.txt`

Если в терминале я введу `./file.txt` то получу ошибку `Permission denied`

Почему `Permission denied`? И что на самом деле должно произойти если просто напрямую обратиться к файлу в терминале? Как Linux воспринимает такие действия?

Comment: А какой Linux-то?

Comment: Как попытку запустить программу или скрипт. Для этого у файла должны быть выставлены права на выполнение соответствующим пользователем (в данном случае root). У вашего файла, скорее всего, такие права не установлены, потому и Permission denied. Но даже если их установить, если это не исполняемый файл и не скрипт, ничего путного не получится.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский а это разве зависит от линукса?

Comment: @defrag, да. К тому же многие пользователи путают "суперпользователя" с "рут-пользователем". Могло случиться так, что человек сделал `sudo cd '/dir'`, а потом уже запускал файл с обычными правами.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский *К тому же многие пользователи путают "суперпользователя" с "рут-пользователем"* - объясните, пожалуйста, в чём разница.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, почитайте на тему *setuid* vs. *seteuid*, хотя я и не думаю, что автор комментария имел это в виду.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Если в терминале я введу `./file.txt` то получу ошибку `Permission denied`

в вашем случае скорее всего у файла не было ни одного (из трёх) битов исполнимости.

"**начать** исполнение" файла можно, если:

- у файла стоит бит исполнимости "для пользователя-владельца" и текущий пользователь как раз и является владельцем файла
- или стоит бит исполнимости "для группы-владельца" и текущий пользователь входит (в том числе и) в эту группу, но не является владельцем файла
- или стоит бит исполнимости "для всех" и текущий пользователь не является ни владельцем файла, ни членом группы, которой принадлежит файл.

---

это, конечно, далеко не исчерпывающий список требований. например, если файловая система, на которой располагается файл, смонтирована с опцией `noexec`, то "начать исполнение" этого файла не выйдет. на более поздних этапах "начала исполнения" могут помешать процессу и всякие "надстройки безопасности" а-ля *selinux*, *apparmor*, и [всякое такое прочее](https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=35852).

---

> Как Linux воспринимает такие действия?

о! до программы *linux* тут ещё очень далеко. сначала ваша *оболочка* (*shell*) принимает решение, что же ей, собственно, делать, в ответ на нажатие вами клавиши *enter*. формы "исполнения" файла могут весьма различаться: помимо упомянутой `./файл` может быть и `./файл | ...`, и `./файл & ...`, и `exec файл` (не говоря уж про всякие там перенаправления потоков). в каждом случае действия будут различными.

в самом примитивном из вариантов, в том, что вы упомянули, `./файл`, оболочка **в конце концов** вызовёт функцию `execve()`, которая в вашей системе реализована, скорее всего, в *libc*. а оттуда уже будет [совершён системный вызов](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-system-calls/) *sys_execve()*. вот только здесь и "вступит в игру" программа *linux*. логика её действий при обработке данного системного вызова тоже весьма разветвлённая. [описана она в](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html):

```
$ man 2 execve
```

возможны четыре глобальных варианта:

1. в начале файла присутствует [elf-header](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)
2. в начале файла присутствует корректный [shebang](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix))
3. (близкий к предыдущему вариант) в начале файла (с указанным смещением) присутствует некое "магическое число" (либо файл имеет определённый суффикс в имени), по поводу чего имеется правило обработки, [зарегистрированное](http://fl47l1n3.net/2015/12/24/binfmt/) при помощи [binfmt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc)
4. если ничего вышеперечисленного не обнаружилось, то формально, согласно стандарту *posix*, "поведение не определено". на практике, скорее всего, будет предпринята попытка интерпретировать файл так, как будто в нём есть *shebang* `#!/bin/sh`. см. ответы на [соответствующий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12296308/4827341).

   т.е., для случая пустого файла, ничего сделано не будет, а программа `/bin/sh` вернёт вашей оболочке нулевой код возврата ("успех").

Comment: я бы к этой фразе `до программы linux тут ещё очень далеко` добавил бы еще такой смысл, что это было за долго до самой программы `linux`, а в общем виде так и вообще относится к `unix-ам`.