# Не могу запустить Ruby код с Git

Tags: git, ruby

Ruby код:

```
#test

def cipher(s)
s.each_char do |chr|
    case chr
        when "a"
            print("0")
        when "b"
            print("1")
        when "c"
            print("2")
        end
    end
end
s = "cabbac"
cipher(s)
```

Git:

```
irogk@DESKTOP-U9V3SLH /c/Sites
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [i386-mingw32]

irogk@DESKTOP-U9V3SLH /c/Sites
$ test.rb
/c/Users/irogk/OneDrive/Desktop/test.rb: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/c/Users/irogk/OneDrive/Desktop/test.rb: line 3: `def cipher(s)'
```

Comment: Игорь, пишите по-русски.

Answer (score 2):

объяснение того, что происходит: [Обращение к файлу напрямую в Linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/810131/178576)

причина: в файле присутствует некорректный [shebang](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix)):

```
#test
```

благодаря чему происходит попытка интерпретировать файл с помощью программы-оболочки.

1. либо укажите корректный, с полным путём к используемому интерпретатору, который можно узнать многими способами. например:

   ```
   $ which ruby
   $ command -v ruby
   $ type ruby
   $ whereis ruby
   ```

   к пример, это `/usr/bin/ruby`. значит, *shebang* должен быть, например, таким:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/ruby
   ```
2. либо явно вызывайте интерпретатор, передавая ему путь к файлу со скриптом в качестве аргумента:

   ```
   $ ruby test.rb
   ```