# Как "запустить" приложение в ELF формате в Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elf

Разработчик выложил старую версию своего приложения, скачав этот файл без расширения, я решил узнать, в каком он формате. Просмотрев его я обнаружил, что он в ELF формате. Как запустить, либо установить это приложение в Ubuntu?

Comment: Просто напрямую взять и запустить, двойным кликом мыши или введя путь к этому файлу в терминале. Только не забудьте выставить файлу права, разрешающие его запуск

Comment: Благодарю, двойной клик не проходит, а вот через терминал "./my_file.elf" все заработало!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

начну с двух цитат. из [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format):

> ELF (англ. Executable and Linkable Format — формат исполнимых и компонуемых файлов) — формат двоичных файлов, используемый во многих современных UNIX-подобных операционных системах, таких как FreeBSD, Linux, Solaris и др.

и из пьесы «мещанин во дворянстве» мольера:

> Журден. Скажите на милость! Сорок с лишком лет говорю прозой - и невдомек!

да, большая часть программ (и библиотек) в ряде операционных систем сохраняются в файлах в формате `elf`. в этом можно убедиться, например, с помощью программы `file` (вывод разбит на строки для удобства обозрения):

```
$ file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked,
interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2,
BuildID[sha1]=6461a544c35b9dc1d172d1a1c09043e487326966, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

если мы скопируем этот файл в текущий каталог без сохранения битов исполнимости:

```
$ cp --no-preserve=mode /bin/ls .
```

то и запустить его просто по имени не сможем:

```
$ ./ls
bash: ./ls: Permission denied
$ ls -l ls
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 147176 Jan 16 20:40 ls
```

надо либо добавить бит исполнимости ([хотя бы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/810245/178576) для вас — владельца файла):

```
$ chmod u+x ls
$ ./ls -l ls
-rwxr--r-- 1 user user 147176 Jan 16 20:40 ls
```

либо напрямую вызвать загрузчик (указан в выводе программы `file` как `interpreter`):

```
$ chmod -x ls
$ /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./ls -l ls
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 147176 Jan 16 20:40 ls
```

Comment: Еще бывают файловые системы, монтированные с атрибутом `noexec`

Comment: @DiD, не будем о грустном.